# Button's like stairs

Tags: html, css

How can i create like step's under button's

Something like this

[Example 1](http://pokit.org/get/img/96e379bccb16083be12ac3cfe8a0b943.jpg)

I can create that with using `&nbsp;` but is there any simplier way ?

Or maybe do you have any idea how to place those button's to looks nice

```
<div id='2' style="display: block;" align="center" >    
    <p class="tekst">&nbsp;<br><br>Bitte bewerten Sie Ihre Zufriedenheit mit:</p>
    <p class="tekst">&nbsp;Wie zufrieden sind Sie mit der Lage des Hotels ?</p>                                     
    <input type='button' class="myButton" />
    <input type='button' class="myButton2"/>
    <input type='button' class="myButton3"/>
    <input type='button' class="myButton4"/>
    <input type='button' class="myButton5"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="mjesto" id="mjesto">                 
</div>
```

Comment: `margin-left` on each button

Comment: *"how to place those button's to looks nice"* Simply one under each other.

Comment: @DanFromGermany didn't know i can use margin's for that

Comment: @t3cho CSS is ment to be universal and can be applied to all elements. Only their behaviour regarding blocking and non-blocking plays a role afaik. But I have to agree with Roko, it looks smarter when they aren't looking like stairs. Maybe I'd use some more typical rating symbols like stars or images people can relate "a rating" with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to study more about the basics of html and css.

Here, I created a fiddle for you.

#### [Fiddle - Original Answer](http://jsfiddle.net/twM92/)

**CSS:**

```
input[type="button"]{ display:block; }
.myButton { margin-left:10px; }
.myButton2{ margin-left:20px; }
.myButton3{ margin-left:30px; }
.myButton4{ margin-left:40px; }
.myButton5{ margin-left:50px; }
```

---

#### [Fiddle - 1 Line CSS Solution (Not Recommended)](http://jsfiddle.net/sTEJQ/97/)

**CSS**

```
li{list-style-type:none;}
```